# Does anyone know a book about Rune Casters/Masters?

Tags: story-identification, books

When I was in America, I began reading a book series. It was a fantasy fiction series about some people who could use other peoples attributes, like their beauty or their intelligence by tattooing a rune on the pair  (so one person would have the rune to take beauty and someone else would have the rune to give beauty and someone would cast a spell or something?)

There were also people who thought it was wrong to take from other humans so they took their attributes from dogs. (Like sight, strengh, speed, smell etc)

It's been bugging me for years and any searches for "rune casting" or "rune masters" just turns up books on how to read runes. Any one got any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [The Runelords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Runelords)? Never read it but the Wiki article discusses a series just like you describe.

Comment: Thats it! thank you so much :D